# Host multiple services that need same ports open on gitlab ci

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

this is an issue I've been postponing for a while but I need to get fixed at some point.

Basically I have two services which I have containerized and registered in my gitlab registers. The two services represent different versions of the same program. In my automated tests I have 2 test suites which are testing for backwards compatibility with these services. The issue that I have is that when my automated tests run, only one service can run fine because there is a conflict over the ports they use I assume and so gitlab can't run all of the services at the same time.

Is there a way to get around this without making the ports specifiable in the code? This option would take the most amount of time and I'd rather leave it as a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

It seems after some digging that making the ports configurable is my only option. As per the kubernetes documentation "You cannot use several services using the same port (e.g., you cannot have two mysql services at the same time)." https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/kubernetes.html